# Google stopped indexing my AMP pages

Tags: google-search, amp

Suddenly Google stopped indexing my AMP pages though they are valid for AMP. What could be the reasons? Considering that I didn't make any changes to my code or content.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but there just isn't enough information for us to be able to answer this. Please see the question marked as a duplicate.

Comment: My question is just about AMP pages. It's not a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: The same principles apply. As stated, there's simply not enough information for us to be able to answer this. If you can edit the question to contain more details, such as factors that changed in regards to your site (e.g., content changes, hosting/DNS issues, penalties, etc...) then it will be added back to the review queue for consideration to be reopened.

Comment: Done. Please re-open.

Comment: You didn't add any details for us to be able to go off of. Without that, it's an [open-ended](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) question and we'd just be making guesses.What are the 38 critical issues in red that it's indicating? Do you have regular non-AMP pages, and were those also affected? You'll need to do some digging around and add those details so that we can possibly answer this. Otherwise, have a look at the duplicate question, it still applies.

Comment: The critical issues doesn't matter here. They are various errors and relative to the number of indexed pages. The number of indexed pages suddenly dropped down, so did the number of critical issues.